# Some doubts about memory management in ios applicato?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, retain, retaincount

1. What is the need for retain an NSObject in ios application?
2. What is the difference between retainCount==1,retainCount=2,.....etc?
3. How properties can handle retaining and releasing instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to retain an objects so that it won't get deallocated while you're using it.
2. The higher the retain count, the more times a retain message has been sent to an object.
3. If you declare the property correctly, assigning values to it will handle the memory management for that instance variable correctly.  That might mean calling `retain` or `release` correctly for object types.

It sure sounds like you need to read some of the documentation.  Perhaps specifically the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)?

Comment: if don't mind can u elaborate The higher the retain count, the more times a retain message has been sent to an object.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question?  Every time you write `[object retain]`, the retain count goes up by one.  In general the specific value of the retain count is not something you should need to know or even care about in the context of writing your program.

Comment: Yesterday read this document,if an NSObject retain count=1,2.., their is any change in memory?

Comment: Well, the retain count variable would change... I'm sure I understand your question.

Comment: I am new in this field,if any mistake in my questiom i am asking excuse . when i am retain/releasing NSObject ,the retain count increate/decrease by one, what happens exactly in memory?

Comment: The retain count increases or decreases by one. That's it.  Nothing else changes.  If the retain count goes to zero, later on something might happen to your object, but as I mentioned above, the specific value of the retain count is not something you ever need to care about when writing your program.

Comment: Yesterday i read two more line that's.                        NSString *myString=[NSString stringWithString:@"this is my String"]; You would need to explicitly retain it? what it means?

Comment: In some time I want to explicitly retain NSObject else getting EXCE_BADACCESS why?

Comment: An object can never have a retain count of zero; retainCount can never return zero.  The retain count of an object is a useless metric and you should never call 'retainCount'.

Comment: Thanks, @bbum.  That's the point I was trying to get across.  I didn't know it couldn't ever be zero, though.  I'll edit and rework that.